# jacob Can't QI object for IDispatch

Tags: java, eclipse, com, jacob

My environment is Java 8, on Windows 7 - 64 bit. So here's my requirement and procedures I followed
java:java version "1.8.0_131" 32 bit
jacob:jacob-1.18-x86.dll &jacob.jar

i use the eclipse to run the following code .it works well.

```
import com.jacob.com.*;
import com.jacob.activeX.*;
public class DispatchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActiveXComponent xl = new ActiveXComponent("Execl.Application");
        Dispatch xlo = (Dispatch)(xl.getObject());
        try {
            System.out.println("version="+xl.getProperty("Version"));
            System.out.println("version="+Dispatch.get(xlo, "Version"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            xl.invoke("Quit", new Variant[] {});
        }
    }
}
```

when i try to use the third party dll and i meet the following execption:

```
import com.jacob.com.*;
import com.jacob.activeX.*;
public class DispatchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActiveXComponent xl = new ActiveXComponent("ProjectParser.1");
        Dispatch xlo = (Dispatch)(xl.getObject());
        try {
            System.out.println("version="+xl.getProperty("Version"));
            System.out.println("version="+Dispatch.get(xlo, "Version"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            xl.invoke("Quit", new Variant[] {});
        }
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't QI object for IDispatch
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
    at DispatchTest.main(DispatchTest.java:5)
```

https://github.com/joval/jacob/blob/master/jni/Dispatch.cpp

can anyone please guide me to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check you COM object with [Oleview.exe tool](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/63930-olecom-object-viewer-oleviewexe-with-tutorial/).
I assume that your object doesn't implement IDispatch interface.
If you still need to use it, you can try your out [Com4J library](http://com4j.kohsuke.org/index.html), which can interact COM Objects without IDispatch interface.

You're gonna need to create java class file for your COM object with tlbimp.jar, which comes with Com4J distribution. See [Com4J tutorials](http://com4j.kohsuke.org/tutorial.html) for more info.